# Windows 10 - Powershell console, cannot vertically scroll

Tags: powershell, scrolling

For some reason I don't get any vertical scrollbars in powershell, and I cannot scroll up to see any commands or output after they've gone out of view.

I can't see the output from my commands if it doesn't all fit on the screen at once.

Does anyone know what I might need to do to fix this?

I can't see any settings in powershell properties to enable or disable vertical scrolling.

If I normalise the window size, it shows the scrollbars, but will only allow scrolling the equivalent maximised size.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I found the solution. I had to increase the Height in "Screen Buffer Size" under "Layout" tab in properties.

Answer (score 0):

settings -> profile -> windows power shell -> advanced ( at bottom ) -> history buffer size -> 999999

[image]