# Windows Terminal can't scroll up

Tags: windows-10, terminal, scrolling, windows-terminal

I'm using [Windows Terminal Preview v0.8.10091.0](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal) on Windows 10. In the past, I can scroll up in a cmd profile.

[image]

But I don't know why, it doesn't work now.

[image]

I suspect it's some directories added to the `PATH` environment variable. I cleared all suspect entries from `PATH` and it still have this issue.

How can I find the root cause of this problem?

### Update

BTW, PowerShell profile works. I can scroll up in it.

Comment: Is there any chance the Properties > Layout > Screen Buffer Size got changed?

Comment: @Dennis No. I checked the settings and nothing special there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't be like me. I had this same issue. Took me some minutes to realize I had turned off scroll on my touchpad plus didn't see the windows scrollbars. Oops.

Answer (score 0):

It's really strange for me.

firstly, I tried this: ( doesn't work )

settings -> profile -> windows power shell -> advanced ( at bottom ) -> history buffer size -> 999999

then I restart my PC, it doesnt work.

then I gave up and installed another terminal: fluent terminal. power shell opened and can not be scroll up.

then (in fluent terminal) I type something randomly , and used my mouse scroll up, it works!

then I came back to "terminal preview", opened power shell, typed something randomly, and scroll up, it works!!!

I really don't know why.
refer to: [Windows 10 - Powershell console, cannot vertically scroll](https://superuser.com/questions/1350823/windows-10-powershell-console-cannot-vertically-scroll/1718013#1718013)